# Simplest css,js pop-up

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-position, css-animations, animate.css

Here is some html,CSS and JavaScript code:

```
<Body onload="document.getElementById('Chrome_popup').style = 'position: fixed; left:0; bottom:10%; height:10%; width:100%;';">
<Div id="pop-up" style="position: fixed; left:0; bottom:-10%; height:10%; width:100%;">
Hi
</Div>
</Body>
```

I want the div to pop-up when document is opened. Please add a transition code for me.

Comment: What kind of transition did you have in mind? Did you already try something? And which element are you trying to pop up; your source is ambiguous.

Comment: @MrLister I want to move #pop-up from down (outside of screen) to up(bottom:10%).

Comment: Move #pop-up from down to up within 1sec

Answer (score 0):

The CSS below is going to help you:

```
#pop-up {
  -webkit-transition:all .8s ease;
  -moz-transition:all .8s ease;
  -ms-transition:all .8s ease;
  -o-transition:all .8s ease;
  transition:all .8s ease;
}
```

By the way, HTML tags start with lowercase, not the upper ones! Use `<body></body>` instead of `<Body></Body>`

```css
#pop-up {
  -webkit-transition:all .8s ease;
  -moz-transition:all .8s ease;
  -ms-transition:all .8s ease;
  -o-transition:all .8s ease;
  transition:all .8s ease;
}
```

```html
<body onload="document.getElementById('pop-up').style = 'position: fixed; left:0; bottom:10%; height:10%; width:100%;';">
<div id="pop-up" style="position: fixed; left:0; bottom:-10%; height:10%; width:100%;">
Hi
</div>
</body>
```